# Написать программу для расшифровки текста методом частотного анализа

Tags: c#, c++, криптография, криптоаналитика

Помогите написать программу по расшифрования на C# или на C++(второй вариант желательнее). Есть два файла, один с обычным русским текстом, а второй зашифрованный текст. Сравнивая реальную частотность символов русского языка из первого файла  с частотностями зашифрованного текста, из второго файла составить таблицу замен алгоритма шифрования и расшифровать зашифрованный текст.

**Зашифрованный текст**

> ЛИЦФЭИЪВУГОЦЛ ,ВУВПФОВЦГНЪУФЬЛВЭФЖЫЛЩЛВЧФЫФСФ,ВУВЗЛОЫУГ,ВЦФВЯФСЖАФЖТАБВЯЖШИФБ,ВЯЛКУАЬАОЮВИУФВЩЖФЭИФЦАЦФ.ВЯГЖУЪДВАЧВЦАБ,ВЛИГСЪДВУВЬГСЦ  ВОГЖГЦЮЫШ ВЯФЖШ,ВНЪЬВЗФЬГЦЮЫЛЩЛВЖЛОСФ,ВШЯАСФЦ,ВЬЪО,ВОУЛ ВЯЖАЬАПЦШ ВТЬКЯШВЯАЖЛЭЫЛЗВЦГОВУВЖШЫГ,ВФВЦФВБЛЖЛТЛВУЪНЖАСЛЗВЬАЙГВГЩЛВЯЛЗГХФЬАОЮВОУГЖБРГОСГОСУГЦЦЪБВЖФЧЗГЖЛУВЛПЫАВУВПГЖЦЛДВЖЛЩЛУЛДВЛЯЖФУГ.ВУСЛЖЛДВ–ВЯЬГПАОСЪД,ВЖЪЭГУФСЪД,ВУАБЖФОСЪДВЗЛЬЛИЛДВПГЬЛУГЫВУВЧФЬЛЗЬГЦЦЛДВЦФВЧФСЪЬЛЫВЫЬГСПФСЛДВЫГЯЫГВ–ВНЪЬВУВЫЛУНЛДЫГ,ВЭГУФЦЪБВНГЬЪБВНЖ ЫФБВАВУВПГЖЦЪБВСФЯЛПЫФБ.
> ЯГЖУЪДВНЪЬВЦГВЫСЛВАЦЛД,ВЫФЫВЗАБФАЬВФЬГЫОФЦИЖЛУАПВНГЖЬАЛЧ,ВЯЖГИОГИФСГЬЮВЯЖФУЬГЦАКВЛИЦЛДВАЧВЫЖШЯЦГДТАБВЗЛОЫЛУОЫАБВЬАСГЖФСШЖЦЪБВФООЛЙАФЙАД,ВОЛЫЖФХГЦЦЛВАЗГЦШГЗЛДВЗФООЛЬАС,ВАВЖГИФЫСЛЖВСЛЬОСЛЩЛВБШИЛЭГОСУГЦЦЛЩЛВЭШЖЦФЬФ,ВФВЗЛЬЛИЛДВОЯШСЦАЫВГЩЛВ–ВЯЛЕСВАУФЦВЦАЫЛЬФГУАПВЯЛЦЪЖГУ,ВЯАТШХАДВЯЛИВЯОГУИЛЦАЗЛЗВНГЧИЛЗЦЪД.
> ЯЛЯФУВУВСГЦЮВПШСЮВЧГЬГЦГ ХАБВЬАЯ,ВЯАОФСГЬАВЯГЖУЪЗВИЛЬЩЛЗВНЖЛОАЬАОЮВЫВЯГОСЖЛВЖФОЫЖФТГЦЦЛДВНШИЛПЫГВОВЦФИЯАОЮ В«ЯАУЛВАВУЛИЪ».
> ИФ,ВОЬГИШГСВЛСЗГСАСЮВЯГЖУШ ВОСЖФЦЦЛОСЮВЕСЛЩЛВОСЖФТЦЛЩЛВЗФДОЫЛЩЛВУГПГЖФ.ВЦГВСЛЬЮЫЛВШВНШИЛПЫА,ВЦЛВАВУЛВУОГДВФЬЬГГ,ВЯФЖФЬЬГЬЮЦЛДВЗФЬЛДВНЖЛЦЦЛДВШЬАЙГ,ВЦГВЛЫФЧФЬЛОЮВЦАВЛИЦЛЩЛВПГЬЛУГЫФ.ВУВСЛСВПФО,ВЫЛЩИФВШЭ,ВЫФЭГСОК,ВАВОАЬВЦГВНЪЬЛВИЪТФСЮ,ВЫЛЩИФВОЛЬЦЙГ,ВЖФОЫФЬАУВЗЛОЫУШ,ВУВОШБЛЗВСШЗФЦГВУФЬАЬЛОЮВЫШИФ-СЛВЧФВОФИЛУЛГВЫЛЬЮЙЛ,В–ВЦАЫСЛВЦГВЯЖАТГЬВЯЛИВЬАЯЪ,ВЦАЫСЛВЦГВОГЬВЦФВОЫФЗГДЫШ,ВЯШОСФВНЪЬФВФЬЬГК.

**Обычный текст**

> Весна – волшебное время года, когда природа оживает после зимней спячки. Воздух наполняется ароматами цветущих цветов, а первые лучи солнца приносят тепло и свет. Деревья распускают свои нежные почки, создавая яркую палитру зелени.
> Пение птиц становится настоящей симфонией, наполняя пространство чистыми и веселыми звуками. Первые теплые дни приносят радость и вдохновение, вызывая желание провести больше времени на свежем воздухе. Весна – это время перемен, новых начинаний и надежд.
> Цветущие сады и парки привлекают внимание своим великолепием. Пестрые ковры из подснежников и нарциссов создают ощущение волшебства. Весенний ветер ласкает кожу, принося с собой аромат земли и цветущих деревьев.
> С каждым днем температура поднимается, и природа преображается. Луга заполняются цветами, а деревья расцветают в нежных оттенках розового, белого и фиолетового. Весеннее солнце пригревает, создавая уют и комфорт.
> Люди также пробуждаются к жизни вместе с природой. Весна приносит с собой позитивные эмоции и желание творить. Пикники, велопрогулки и встречи на свежем воздухе становятся популярными занятиями. Люди улыбаются, наслаждаясь яркими красками и приятной атмосферой весенних дней.
> Весна – время надежды и обновления. Она напоминает нам о бесконечном цикле жизни и о том, что даже после холодной зимы приходит тепло и светлое время. Это пора, когда душа наполняется вдохновением, а сердце – радостью.

**Моя программа**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string plainTextPath = "input3.txt";
        string encryptedTextPath = "input2.txt";

        string plainText = File.ReadAllText(plainTextPath).ToLower();
        string encryptedText = File.ReadAllText(encryptedTextPath).ToLower();

        Dictionary<char, int> plainTextFrequency = GetCharacterFrequency(plainText);
        Dictionary<char, int> encryptedTextFrequency = GetCharacterFrequency(encryptedText);

        Dictionary<char, char> decryptionTable = CreateDecryptionTable(plainTextFrequency, encryptedTextFrequency);

        string decryptedText = DecryptText(encryptedText, decryptionTable);

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Text:");
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Dictionary<char, int> GetCharacterFrequency(string text)
    {
        return text
            .Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
            .GroupBy(char.ToLower)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    }

    static Dictionary<char, char> CreateDecryptionTable(Dictionary<char, int> realFrequency, Dictionary<char, int> encryptedFrequency)
    {
        var sortedRealFrequency = realFrequency.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Select(pair => pair.Key).ToArray();
        var sortedEncryptedFrequency = encryptedFrequency.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Select(pair => pair.Key).ToArray();

        Dictionary<char, char> decryptionTable = new Dictionary<char, char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedRealFrequency.Length; i++)
        {
            decryptionTable[sortedEncryptedFrequency[i]] = sortedRealFrequency[i];
        }

        return decryptionTable;
    }

    static string DecryptText(string encryptedText, Dictionary<char, char> decryptionTable)
    {
        return new string(encryptedText.Select(c => decryptionTable.ContainsKey(c) ? decryptionTable[c] : c).ToArray());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: И в чём же у вас сложность?

Comment: найти частоту символов двух текстов я могу, но когда сопоставляю из и вывожу расшифрованный текст выходит белиберда

Comment: Так приложите код вашей программы прямо в вопросе и вам тогда помогут разобраться, почему она не работает. Примерно так устроен этот сайт.

Comment: Добавил программу

Comment: Я уже сам попробовал на Питоне дешифратор написать и тоже какая-то фигня выходит. Причём не важно - убирать знаки пунктуации или их тоже через частоты дешифровать. Так то судя по длине "слов" в зашифрованном тексте, там явно пробелы тоже какой-то буквой зашифрованы, иначе бы не было таких длинных "слов".

Comment: А вообще частоты в примере русского текста не характерные. Обычно в другом порядке буквы идут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0 Ну и часто ещё проценты некоторых букв весьма похожи, поэтому они могут в разных текстах немного в разном порядке идти. Это точно корректное задание и его нужно именно на приведённом примере текста решать?

Comment: Так то я когда-то давно уже писал разные штуки на основе частотности, кажется и дешифратор писал, но нужно искать. Брал прям готовые таблички частот и дешифровал по ним. Но, повторюсь, буквы могут не всегда идти в том же порядке по частотам.

Comment: А программа с виду правильно в принципе написана. Хотя я бы не выкидывал знаки препинания из анализа частот, по вышеописанным причинам.

Comment: Так вы можете уточнить - откуда такая задача взялась, корректная ли она вообще или вы просто предполагаете, что тут такая шифровка? Как вариант же может быть и так, что шифр идёт с какими-то сдвигами дополнительными в зависимости от позиции буквы в слове, т.е. нет стабильной таблицы дешифрации для всего текста сразу.

Comment: Задача с моего колледжа, там необходимо расшифровать текст методом частного анализа. Никаких сдвигов и тд нет

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как сделать правильно, но сделал так, подсчитал буквы в первом тексте и во втором, ничего не увидел, обратил внимание что "В" - пробел, появилось разделение по словам, заметил два слова "ФЬЬГК" "ФЬЬГГ" подставил буквы по частоте примерно в цикл "ФЬЬГГ" среди вариантов была только "аллее", поставил буквы, появились какие-то слова, переставил буквы правильно.
Не мог считать строку пока не поставил в начале `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

> однажды весною, в час небывало жаркого заката, в москве, на
> патриарших прудах, появились два гражданина. первый из них, одетый в
> летню серенькую пару, был маленького роста, упитан, лыс, свою
> приличную шляпу пирожком нес в руке, а на хорошо выбритом лице его
> помещались сверхъестественных размеров очки в черной роговой оправе.
> второй – плечистый, рыжеватый, вихрастый молодой человек в заломленной
> на затылок клетчатой кепке – был в ковбойке, жеваных белых брюках и в
> черных тапочках.юпервый был не кто иной, как михаил александрович
> берлиоз, председатель правления одной из крупнейших московских
> литературных ассоциаций, сокращенно именуемой массолит, и редактор
> толстого художественного журнала, а молодой спутник его – поэт иван
> николаевич понырев, пишущий под псевдонимом бездомный.юпопав в тень
> чуть зеленеющих лип, писатели первым долгом бросились к пестро
> раскрашенной будочке с надписью «пиво и воды».юда, следует отметить
> первую странность этого страшного майского вечера. не только у
> будочки, но и во всей аллее, параллельной малой бронной улице, не
> оказалось ни одного человека. в тот час, когда уж, кажется, и сил не
> было дышать, когда солнце, раскалив москву, в сухом тумане валилось
> куда-то за садовое кольцо, – никто не пришел под липы, никто не сел на
> скамейку, пуста была аллея.

```
{'В': ' ', 'Л': 'о', 'Г': 'е', 'Ф': 'а', 'Ц': 'н', 'А': 'и', 'Ь': 'л', 'О': 'с', 'У': 'в', 'Ж': 'р',
     'С': 'т', 'Ы': 'к', 'Я': 'п', 'И': 'д', 'Ъ': 'ы', 'Ш': 'у', 'Д': 'й', 'З': 'м', 'Б': 'х', 'П': 'ч',
     'Ю': 'ь', 'Н': 'б', 'Щ': 'г', 'Ч': 'з', 'Э': 'ж', 'Т': 'ш', 'Й': 'ц', 'К': 'я', 'Х': 'щ', ' ': 'ю',
     'Е': 'э', 'Р': 'ъ'}
```

Обратите внимание на "ю", там другой пробел, не такой как между словами.

Comment: А, ну вот, по сравнению с частотой букв, получающейся из приведённого в вопросе текста, все замены кроме пробела оказались не на месте, а на несколько позиций выше или ниже. К стандартной частоте букв русского языка это ближе, кстати, но тоже не совсем совпадает. Непонятно, как это нормально программно подобрать, без ручного подбора.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я пробовал аналогичный вопрос решить, частотный анализ букв не помогает, может слоги как-то считать, где автор, их там учат как это решать.

Comment: Да, частота слогов - это хорошо, кстати. Я это тоже где-то применял. Может со слогами лучше будет, чем с отдельными буквами.

Comment: помесь со словарным анализом, т.е. подобраны подходящие последовательности из словаря, частотный анализ слогов тоже оттуда. Собственно, в эру до машинных шифраторов вроде "Энигмы" основной защитой от этого было использование огромного количества аббревиатур , что стало "военной" традицией-мемом позднее - сколько не подбирай, в тексте будут нелегальные слова.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Ну, это надо словарь держать. Я пробовал `pymorphy2` приспособить для распознавания "легальных" слов, но он слишком хитрый, часто и какую-то похожую на слова лабуду признаёт за легальные слова )

Comment: @CrazyElf а каким методом считается анализ длины слов? вот, если мы сказали что В -пробел (а это можно было сделать методом перебора всех вариантов), то "ВУВ", это либо "в", либо "и",  либо "я" (а предполагая наличие пунктуации - и тире).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "Перебор всех вариантов" в данном случае - это что-то нереальное. 32 буквы (без ё) даже в степени длины слова, к которому мы подбираем варианты, при слове из 5 букв - это какое-то просто дикое число получается. А если для всех 32 букв (плюс ещё пробелы всякие, ну да ладно) замены перебирать - это мы до конца жизни Вселенной варианты не подберём. То, что В - это пробел, было подобрано просто потому, что пробел и В - это самые частые символы в обоих текстах. А вот дальше начинаются проблемы уже с другими символами текстов - популярность букв в них не одинаковая.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Так то ваша идея с подбором букв под короткие слова хорошая, это сильно ограничивает перебор, но что делать дальше с более длинными словами.

Comment: @CrazyElf  Я искал "особенные" слова типа ФЬЬГГ

Comment: @Oopss Интуитивно понятно, но как это формализовать программно? )

Comment: мм... в языке ограиченное количество двойных букв. те "ее", "оо", "лл", "сс", "рр", "нн"... (И вроде как только одна тройная - "еее"? на это можно забить), это можно считать "слогами"..

Comment: @CrazyElf я забыл "а". Я в даком виде перебор представлял. Пробел очен сложный элемент по частоте - зависит от текста. Но , если мы для каждого варианта подстановки посчитаем длину слов и составим гистограмму - длина слова - частота слова, то можно сравнить с тем, что возможно в языке. Вряд ли это пробел если нет ни одного "слова" длиной меньше 4 букв, или  если у нас все слова короче 5. Тут еще хорошо шарить в линейном программировании, чтобы не делать повторные поиск при подстановке. Шаблон "легковес" тоже в помощь. Но все уже тянет скорее на диссертацию.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Ну вот от автора вопроса видимо и требуется хоть какое-то исследование провести, а не просто программу написать с однозначным сопоставлением частот букв в текстах.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Про "еее" я знаю, это длинношеее и змееед

Comment: И контра в виде аббревиатуры ООО!